# Issues with JavaScript isNaN

Tags: javascript

Having a bit of trouble with the use of isNaN in JavaScript. 
A user inputs a phone number which I then check for it's length, and to see if it only contains numerical values.
While I can get it to work for the length of the input, I can't seem to get 'isNaN' to work in order to check the input.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#mobile').on('change', function (e) {

      mobile = $("#mobile").val();  
      test = isNaN(mobile);

      if(mobile.length == 10 || mobile.length == 11 && test == true)  
        {     
          correct_mobile = true;  
        }  
      else  
        {  
          alert('incorrect mobile number');   
          correct_mobile = false;  
        }   
      });
    });
```

Comment: Why do you think there is an issue? What's the input and expected output? I think the issue is rather with your condition. `a || b && c` evaluates as `a || (b && c)`. I.e. you are testing whether the input is 10 *arbitrary* characters or 11 digits. But without details, this is just a guess.

Comment: Please declare your local variables with `var`.

Comment: Also don't use loose comparison with booleans. `test == true` is `true` for `true`, `1`, `'1'`, `[1]` and anything else that can be coerced to the number `1` (granted `isNaN` either returns `true` or `false`, but still).

Comment: `isNaN` returns true if the input isn't a number. So, `test` is true if the input is invalid. And according to your conditional, if `test == true` then `correct_mobile = true`...I think you got mixed up. It should be `test == false`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add parenthesis like so

```
if( (mobile.length == 10 || mobile.length == 11) && test == true)  
    ^                                          ^
```

Otherwise, it will be true as long as mobile.length is 10 regardless of test

Answer (score 5):

Not a good idea to assume phone numbers are numeric as they might have spaces, commas, brackets, dashes or pluses in them. Eg +61 (0) 123-456-789

Plus any leading zero will be removed when the string is converted to a number.

Better to use a library that can properly validate all kinds of phone numbers like this one: https://github.com/googlei18n/libphonenumber

[Demo](https://rawgit.com/googlei18n/libphonenumber/master/javascript/i18n/phonenumbers/demo-compiled.html)

Comment: Cheers for the suggestion, will check it out.

Answer (score 1):

`isNaN` returns true if the input is not a number. In the case of a phone number that consists of only numbers, `isNaN` would have to return false in order for the number to be considered valid.

So in your logic, you don't want `test` to be true - it should be `false` in order for the validation to pass.

```
if((mobile.length == 10 || mobile.length == 11) && test == false)  
{     
    correct_mobile = true;  
}
```